# MongoDB $regex query to number fails

Tags: regex, mongodb

I stored info like this format on my MongoDB

```
{
  name: 'Eric',
  account: 13310
},
{
  name: 'Ivan',
  account: 12120
}
```

this is my noSQL sentence

```
db.users.find( "account": { $regex: /13/, $options: 'i' } );
```

But I got an error

```
Error: error: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "$regex has to be a string",
        "code" : 2,
        "codeName" : "BadValue"
}
```

How could I make the query, I want to find whatever contains "13" on `account` index. I read about parse `account` index to String, but, the collection has over 100K documents, this is not the way.

***I´m looking for this SQL Sentence***

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE ACCOUNT LIKE '%13%'
```

Comment: Did you try turning it into a [string](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)? `$regex: '13'`. Do you want to use the case insensitive flag for 13?

Comment: I tried and it does not returns anything. I used insensitive because account won´t be the unique index to search

Comment: Then, try a RegExp constructor. `{ $regex: new RegExp(value, 'i') }`. If `value` can contain special chars, you may need to eascape it.

Comment: value doesn´t contains special chars, I´m looking this sentece `SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE ACCOUNT LIKE '%13%'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you've seen, `$regex` only works with string fields; so because `account` is a numeric field, your query fails.  Starting with MongoDB 4.0, you can use an aggregate pipeline to dynamically add a [`$toString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) version of `account` that you query against using a regex:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {$addFields: {accountStr: {$toString: '$account'}}},
    {$match: {accountStr: /13/}}
])
```

The alternative would be to store a string copy of the `account` field in your documents that you could directly use.

Comment: Monster! Thank you Sensei.

Comment: Just noting that when I tried this myself, a query which takes 0.36 seconds using direct integer match, took over 7 seconds to convert to string and perform the match.

Comment: I basically used this solution, but Azure Cosmos DB (which claims "wire equivalent" Mongo support) was giving back an error: "$toString is not supported". So I worked around it using the $substr feature.    {$addFields: {accountStr: { $substr: [ "$account", 0, 20] }}},

Comment: Just to help other guys: If you want to add dynamic value for accountStr on {$match: {accountStr: /13/}} you can do it like so: {$match: {accountStr: new RegExp(YOURINPUT.toString())}}

Answer (score -4):

I had a same problem, but i found a solution

Use like this:

"account": "/[A-z]*13/i"

Answer (score -5):

Try this bro..

```js
db.users.find( "account": { $regex: new RegExp( '^13' ), $options: 'i' } );
```

Comment: The MongoDB $regex operator can only be used against string values.